# SutieScript RESTlet 'Missing a required argument: MapReduceScriptTask.scriptId'

Tags: mapreduce, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a RESTlet that I am working to use to call a Map Reduce Script.  However, I am getting the following error:

```
SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT, message:task.submit: Missing a required argument: MapReduceScriptTask.scriptId
```

Here is the code for this particular Function:

```
function bulkUpdate( request ) {
    // Call Map/Reduce Script
    var mapReduceScriptTask = task.create({
        taskType: task.TaskType.MAP_REDUCE,
        scriptID : 'customscript_transaction_bulk_update',
        deploymentId : 'customdeploy_transaction_bulk_update',
        params : {
            "custscript_requestbody" : request['recList']
        }
    });

    var mapReduceScriptTaskId = mapReduceScriptTask.submit();
    var taskStatus = task.checkStatus({
        taskID : mapReduceScriptTaskId
    });
```

I tried the numeric `id` as well as the string, and with no luck.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
scriptID : 'customscript_transaction_bulk_update',
```

vs

```
scriptId : 'customscript_transaction_bulk_update',
```